# LoadError: cannot load such file -- rmagick with dicom gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, imagemagick, dicom, rmagick

I am writing a job that converts dcm to jpg images using the dicom gem

here is the  code

```
require 'RMagick'
require 'dicom'
include Magick
include DICOM


class DicomtojpgJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :dicom

  def perform(*args)
    puts "were are here"
    dcm_filename = args[0]
    dcm = DObject.read(dcm_filename)
    puts dcm.summary
    dcm_image = dcm.image
    name = dcm_filename.split('.')
    dcm_image.normalize.write(name[0]+".jpg")

    # img = ImageList.new("IM-0004-0044.jpg")
    # img.display
    # args[0].update_attributes(:asset_path_url)
    puts args[0]

    exit
  end

end
```

here is what i get on console

```
DICOM Object Properties:Byte Order (CPU):     Little Endian
-------------------------------------------
Source:               File (successfully read): /home/aditya/orthoweb/public/patient-summary-assets/56c6b0b943fe4728c8000007_photo_20160219_122843.dcm

DICOM Object Properties:

Modality:             MR Image Storage-------------------------------------------

Source:               File (successfully read): /home/aditya/orthoweb/public/patient-summary-assets/56c6b0b943fe4728c8000007_photo_20160219_151307.dcm
Modality:             MR Image Storage
Meta Header:          Yes
Value Representation: Explicit
Byte Order (File):    Little Endian
Pixel Data:           Yes
Image Size:           512*288
Number of frames:     1
Meta Header:          YesPhotometry:           MONOCHROME2
Compression:          JPEG 2000 Image Compression

Value Representation: ExplicitBits per Pixel:       16

Byte Order (File):    Little Endian-------------------------------------------

Pixel Data:           Yes
Source:               File (successfully read): /home/aditya/orthoweb/public/patient-summary-assets/56c6b0b943fe4728c8000007_photo_20160219_151307.dcm
Modality:             MR Image Storage
Image Size:           512*288Meta Header:          Yes
Value Representation: Explicit

Number of frames:     1Byte Order (File):    Little Endian

Photometry:           MONOCHROME2Pixel Data:           Yes
Image Size:           512*288

Number of frames:     1Compression:          JPEG 2000 Image Compression

Bits per Pixel:       16Photometry:           MONOCHROME2

-------------------------------------------Compression:          JPEG 2000 Image Compression

Source:               File (successfully read): /home/aditya/orthoweb/public/patient-summary-assets/56c6b0b943fe4728c8000007_photo_20160219_122843.dcmBits per Pixel:       16

Modality:             MR Image Storage
Meta Header:          Yes
Value Representation: Explicit
Byte Order (File):    Little Endian
Pixel Data:           Yes
Image Size:           512*288
Number of frames:     1
2016-02-19T10:07:18.291Z 17868 TID-1ho0x0 DicomtojpgJob JID-4fc6a66b41be878a632b7d9e INFO: fail: 0.014 sec
2016-02-19T10:07:18.291Z 17868 TID-1ho0x0 WARN: {"class"=>"ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter::JobWrapper", "wrapped"=>"DicomtojpgJob", "queue"=>"dicom", "args"=>[{"job_class"=>"DicomtojpgJob", "job_id"=>"345b5c25-82fb-49e7-a59d-b4a5eaf971b6", "queue_name"=>"dicom", "arguments"=>["/home/aditya/orthoweb/public/patient-summary-assets/56c6b0b943fe4728c8000007_photo_20160219_151307.dcm"]}], "retry"=>true, "jid"=>"4fc6a66b41be878a632b7d9e", "created_at"=>1455874987.2288666, "enqueued_at"=>1455876438.270517, "error_message"=>"cannot load such file -- rmagick", "error_class"=>"LoadError", "failed_at"=>1455874987.2376463, "retry_count"=>6, "retried_at"=>1455876438.2907836}
Photometry:           MONOCHROME2
Compression:          JPEG 2000 Image Compression
Bits per Pixel:       162016-02-19T10:07:18.291Z 17868 TID-1ho0x0 WARN: LoadError: cannot load such file -- rmagick
```

I followed this issue on the github page [here](https://github.com/dicom/ruby-dicom/issues/49)
It suggested that if i am able to convert the dcm image to jpg directly using the command `convert -debug module IM-0001-0001.dcm IM.jpg` then dicom should not show any error.
I am able to convert it to jpg using the console but dicom is throwing an `error 2016-02-19T09:24:03.960Z 14165 TID-1kcakw WARN: LoadError: cannot load such file -- rmagick`

Comment: Have you got the JPEG2000 delegate installed? Can you share the DICOM image for me to test?

Comment: go to this http://www.osirix-viewer.com/datasets/ and download the first zip folder

Comment: @Mark Setchell how can i verify that i have  JPEG2000 delegate installed

Comment: Run `identify -version`

Comment: it give the following outputVersion: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2014-03-06 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP

Comment: If you had it installed, you would get something like this `identify -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.3-0 Q16 x86_64 2016-02-19 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2016 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules
Delegates (built-in): bzlib fontconfig freetype jng jp2 jpeg lcms ltdl lzma openexr png tiff webp x xml lib`

Comment: how can i install it can you share a command

Comment: I use ImageMagick at the command-line and with Magick++ under OSX, not with Ruby and not on Linux I am afraid. Basically, **I think** when you do your installation, you need to run `./configure` at some point. When you are there, run `./configure --help` and look for `JP` and/or 2000 like this `./configure --help | grep -Ei "JP|2000" and it should tell you the switches you need to add.

Comment: i have installed and it says JPEG v1           --with-jpeg=yes       yes
JPEG-2000         --with-jp2=yes        yes

Comment: but still my issue is not resolved, it still throws the same error

Comment: Are you still on version 6.7? That is probably 2-3 years old. Please try updating that too.

Comment: @Zajn please have a look at this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed by upgrading rmagick to 2.13.4 or later.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the first image from the repository you suggested and ran the following command:

```
convert -debug module IM-0001-0001.dcm a.jpg
```

**Output**

```
2016-02-19T12:25:56+00:00 0:00.000 0.000u 6.9.3 Module convert[86871]: module.c/OpenModule/1286/Module
  Searching for module "DCM" using filename "dcm.la"
2016-02-19T12:25:56+00:00 0:00.000 0.000u 6.9.3 Module convert[86871]: module.c/GetMagickModulePath/556/Module
  Searching for coder module file "dcm.la" ...
2016-02-19T12:25:56+00:00 0:00.000 0.000u 6.9.3 Module convert[86871]: module.c/OpenModule/1295/Module
  Opening module at path "/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.3-0_2/lib/ImageMagick//modules-Q16/coders/dcm.la"
2016-02-19T12:25:56+00:00 0:00.000 0.000u 6.9.3 Module convert[86871]: module.c/OpenModule/1322/Module
  Method "RegisterDCMImage" in module "DCM" at address 0x1076bd758
2016-02-19T12:25:56+00:00 0:00.000 0.000u 6.9.3 Module convert[86871]: module.c/OpenModule/1336/Module
  Method "UnregisterDCMImage" in module "DCM" at address 0x1076c0ff2
2016-02-19T12:25:56+00:00 0:00.000 0.000u 6.9.3 Module convert[86871]: module.c/OpenModule/1286/Module
  Searching for module "JP2" using filename "jp2.la"
2016-02-19T12:25:56+00:00 0:00.000 0.000u 6.9.3 Module convert[86871]: module.c/GetMagickModulePath/556/Module
  Searching for coder module file "jp2.la" ...
2016-02-19T12:25:56+00:00 0:00.000 0.000u 6.9.3 Module convert[86871]: module.c/OpenModule/1295/Module
  Opening module at path "/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.3-0_2/lib/ImageMagick//modules-Q16/coders/jp2.la"
2016-02-19T12:25:56+00:00 0:00.000 0.000u 6.9.3 Module convert[86871]: module.c/OpenModule/1322/Module
  Method "RegisterJP2Image" in module "JP2" at address 0x1076e3a24
2016-02-19T12:25:56+00:00 0:00.000 0.000u 6.9.3 Module convert[86871]: module.c/OpenModule/1336/Module
  Method "UnregisterJP2Image" in module "JP2" at address 0x1076e572e
2016-02-19T12:25:56+00:00 0:00.000 0.000u 6.9.3 Module convert[86871]: module.c/OpenModule/1286/Module
  Searching for module "JPEG" using filename "jpeg.la"
2016-02-19T12:25:56+00:00 0:00.000 0.000u 6.9.3 Module convert[86871]: module.c/GetMagickModulePath/556/Module
  Searching for coder module file "jpeg.la" ...
2016-02-19T12:25:56+00:00 0:00.000 0.000u 6.9.3 Module convert[86871]: module.c/OpenModule/1295/Module
  Opening module at path "/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.3-0_2/lib/ImageMagick//modules-Q16/coders/jpeg.la"
2016-02-19T12:25:56+00:00 0:00.000 0.000u 6.9.3 Module convert[86871]: module.c/OpenModule/1322/Module
  Method "RegisterJPEGImage" in module "JPEG" at address 0x107e9ce7c
2016-02-19T12:25:56+00:00 0:00.000 0.000u 6.9.3 Module convert[86871]: module.c/OpenModule/1336/Module
  Method "UnregisterJPEGImage" in module "JPEG" at address 0x107ea07b3
```

[image]

I think the issue is that you are missing the JPEG2000 module. You can check your installed delegates with

```
identify -version

Version: ImageMagick 6.9.3-0 Q16 x86_64 2016-02-19 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2016 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib fontconfig freetype jng jp2 jpeg lcms ltdl lzma openexr png tiff webp x xml lib
```

Here you see I have jp2. If you are missing that module, when you install and run `./configure`, try adding the following to find which switches you need:

```
./configure --help | grep -Ei "JP|2000"
```

Then run `configure` and `make` and `make install` in the usual way.

Comment: this works fine for me as well, problem is when i try to convert it using the dicom gem via a Job in rails

Comment: Oh, YIKES! You are well beyond my sphere of knowledge - I can only imagine there is a Ruby config file somewhere that needs to know the path to ImageMagick delegates or shared libraries. Can you get more verbose debug output from your Rails job somehow? Or try running a simpler job that doesn't need JPEG2000 - e.g. `convert image.gif image.jpg`?

Answer (score 0):

It is still not working with RMagick.
But working fine with mini_magick

require 'mini_magick'

DICOM.image_processor = :mini_magick